# MYSQL, PHP) get values from all columns from multiple tables using UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql, union

I need to loop two different tables and get values from all columns.

I tried use UNION ALL to solve my problem.

Code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['country'])){
        $sql = "SELECT name, capital, population,description,null FROM countries WHERE name ='France'
        
        UNION ALL
             SELECT null,null,null,null,attraction_name FROM attraction_list WHERE country_name='France'
        ";
        mysqli_select_db($conn,'travelapp') or die("database not found");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result){
            $countryName;$capital;$population;$description;$attraction;
            while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                $countryName=$row[0];
                $capital=$row[1];
                $population=$row[2];
                $description=$row[3];
                $attraction=$row[4];
            }
            $resultArray = array(
                'country'=>$countryName,
                'capital'=>$capital,
                'population'=>$population,
                'description'=>$description,
                'attraction'=>$attraction
            );
            echo json_encode($resultArray);
        }
    }
```

However, this code doesn't work as I expected. I expected to print out

name, capital, population,description from countries table
and
attraction_name from  attraction_list table.

So the output which I expected should look like this:

> {"country":France, "capital":Paris, "population": 64750000, "description":Some text, "attraction":La Vieille Charite}

but what does my php print out now:
[image]

Is it issue with while loop? or maybe there are much better solution than UNION ALL?

Comment: Did you run this query directly in your database? using cmdline, phpmyadmin, or any mysql client?

Comment: @Ibu yes I tried it in phpmyadmin and in my browser. Tried with the same sql code. I think sql code works fine because in phpmyadmin I get all values. but in browser, I get some strange result. I am guessing may be while loop is incorrect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is a `LEFT JOIN`. Use a `LEFT JOIN` in case there are countries with no attractions. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.name, c.capital, c.population, c.description, a.attraction_name 
        FROM countries c
        LEFT JOIN attraction_list a ON a.country_name = c.name
        WHERE c.name ='France'";
```

This query will give you multiple rows if there are multiple attractions in a country e.g.

```
{"country":France, "capital":Paris, "population": 64750000, "description":Some text, "attraction":La Vieille Charite},
{"country":France, "capital":Paris, "population": 64750000, "description":Some text, "attraction":Eiffel Tower}
```

If you would like only one row e.g.

```
{"country":France, "capital":Paris, "population": 64750000, "description":Some text, "attraction":La Vieille Charite, Eiffel Tower}
```

you could use `GROUP BY` to aggregate e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.name, c.capital, c.population, c.description, GROUP_CONCAT(a.attraction_name)
        FROM countries c
        LEFT JOIN attraction_list a ON a.country_name = c.name
        WHERE c.name ='France'
        GROUP BY c.name";
```

Comment: Oh thanks it works great in my phpmyadmin. Will check if it works in my php code later.